# mysql limit and offset in large table

Tags: mysql, limit, offset

I have a single table with 800000 records, I want to select record from 100000 and limit is 10

### My query is :

```
SELECT * FROM `customercsv` WHERE insert_status = 0 order by id  limit 10 OFFSET 100000
```

But the record is start from 103474.

Here with i attached the screen for your further reference.

[image]

Comment: Are there any records from 100000 to 103474?

Comment: I don't know that lakh is a well known number: 1 lakh === 100,000, so you're talking about 800,000 records, correct?

Comment: How many rows from 1-103474 have been deleted? How many of them have `insert_status = 0`?

Comment: @hjpotter92 3474 i'd say,

Comment: yes it having the record from 100000 to 103474

Comment: And how many don't match the `where` clause? This query looks fine. What are the results of ```SELECT * FROM `customercsv` WHERE id=100001```, for example?

Comment: @senthil you have 3474 deleted records with an id smaller than 100.000. therefore, when you use the Offset 100000, it will start at id 1003474 to *really* skip 100000 rows.

Comment: ya its returning only one record the id of the record is 100001

Comment: what does `SELECT COUNT(id) FROM customercsv WHERE id <= 103474` return?

Comment: There are lots of circumstances in which an auto-incremented id might skip a few numbers. If you want records between 100000 and 100010 then you need to specify that in the WHERE clause.

Comment: i got the total 103474 records to run SELECT COUNT(id) FROM customercsv WHERE id <= 103474

Comment: this is strange - what kind of column is id? int? varchar? auto-increment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the results starting at `id = 100000`, specify that in the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT *
FROM `customercsv`
WHERE insert_status = 0
    AND id >= 1000000
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 10
```

---

Your current query, with `OFFSET` fetches data for the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `customercsv`
WHERE insert_status = 0
ORDER BY id
```

and then, skips the first **100000** rows and shows you the 10 results after that. There are, therefore `3474` rows such that `insert_status` is not **0**. You can confirm this by running:

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM customercsv
WHERE id <= 103474
    AND insert_status <> 0
```